# How to find all folders within a folder in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, java-native-interface, registry

There are already lots of questions on how to read/write windows and their are number of good jni/non-jni solutions available. I've gone through a few, but neither of them provided means to traverse the registry.

By traversal, I mean to say that I want to know all sub-folders of a particular folder in Windows Registry and then all keys within that folder.

The available solutions, let's one read the registry key, but not the registry folder to find the sub-folders within.

Comment: Terminology note: What you're calling folders are really called *keys*. Inside a key can be other keys (subkeys), as well as *values*. A value has a *name* and *data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was requiring some solution in java, but then found some VBScrip that can do this much easily

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture"

Sub EnumerateKeys(hive, key)
  'WScript.Echo key
  reg.EnumKey hive, key, arrSubKeys
  If Not IsNull(arrSubKeys) Then
    For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
      EnumerateKeys hive, key & "\" & subkey
    Next
  End If
  reg.GetDWORDValue hive,key,"DeviceState",nn
  'WScript.Echo key & " = " & nn
    If nn=268435457 Then
        'WScript.Echo "Good morning!"
        reg.SetDWORDValue hive,key,"DeviceState",1
    ElseIf  nn=1 Then
        reg.SetDWORDValue hive,key,"DeviceState",268435457
    Else
        'WScript.Echo "Have a nice day!"
    End If
End Sub

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

EnumerateKeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath
```

Above script not only iterates, over keys & subkeys, it also reads and compares and then sets DWORD values.

[Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Leverage the Windows API for registry access, and expose it via JNI.

Windows Registry API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx
   Key function being `RegEnumKeyEx`

Here is a tutorial on walking the registry keys in c++:  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/ce/registry/article.php/c8301/Walking-The-Registry-Tree.htm

Comment: Thanks for replying. I ultimately ended up using VBScript, that seemed nice, easy and small.